# Выполнение тестов java selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Приветствую. Возникла следующая проблема. Есть 5 тестов. Если запускать по отдельность проходят, если запустить все вместе, то тесты проходят через раз, какой-то и упадет. Падает один из двух тестов, в которых есть идентичные шаги, где и происходит падение.
То есть:
Тест1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Тест2: 1 2 3 4 5 6

При запуске в шагах 3 4 5 происходит падение в одном из тестов. Не могу определить почему такая нестабильность тестов. Тестируемый сайт почти полностью на JS (на это грешу, но могу ошибаться).

Comment: хотелось бы увидеть код тестов и файл настройки параллелизации

Comment: Благодарю, за ответ. Вопрос решен уже. Какое решение использовал уже не припомню. Еще раз спасибо.